# class field with a type defined in an anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, anonymous-types

I have a struct defined in an anonymous namespace.  Then I also want to have a class defined which has a field of that struct type.
I forward declare the struct in the header file:

```
struct my_str;

class my_class {
public:
  struct my_str *field;
  void method();
};
```

and then in the cpp file I have the actual type defined and some methods using it:

```
namespace {
struct my_str {
  int data;
};
}

void helper(struct my_str * obj) {
  std::cout << obj->data;
}

void my_class::method() {
  helper(field);
}
```

This doesn't compile:

test.cc:10:20: error: reference to ‘my_str’ is ambiguous

It lists 2 definitions for my_str, the forward declaration and the one from the anonymous namespace.
Is there a way to disambiguate and make this compile?

Comment: No way. Types have linkage. If you want the member to refer to that type in different TUs, it must have external linkage.

Comment: Why is `my_str` in an unnamed namespace, but `my_class` isn't?

Comment: because my_str is completely private and no one should know anything about it.  But we want this world-facing class to have a reference to it.

Comment: If your class is going to have a pointer in it anyway, maybe you should consider the [pImpl idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2019/01/the-pimpl-idiom/). Instead of trying to have a pointer to a struct in an anonymous namespace, just have a pointer to your whole implementation. The implementation can refer to a struct defined in an unnamed namespace, so long as it's in the same cpp file as your implementation, which it looks like you want to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous namespace hides the name from the outside, so you can't use that - there is no way for an outsider to refer to that type.

You don't *need* to write the definition in an anonymous namespace - it is hidden outside anyway.
However, this will lead to undefined behaviour if you have another global type with the same name, due to the One Definition Rule.

Probably the best solution is to hide the definition inside `my_class` instead:

Header:

```
class my_class {
public:
  // Note the separate declaration; a one-liner would declare 
  // that there is a global `my_str`.
  struct my_str; // Not defined for the outside world, but the name is accessible.
  my_str *field;
  void method();
};
```

Source:

```
struct my_class::my_str
{
    int data;
};

namespace
{
    void helper(my_data::my_str* obj) {
      std::cout << obj->data;
    }
}

void my_class::method() {
  helper(field);
}
```

Comment: problem is that I really don't want to mess with the my_str definition as this is all legacy code with a bunch of things linking against it.  But I think i found a woraround.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this approach and would like to hear what people think.
"every problem in computer science can be solved by adding another level of indirection"

.h:

```
struct my_str_wrap;

class my_class {
public:
  struct my_str_wrap* field;
  void method();
};
```

.cc:

```
namespace {
struct my_str {
  int data;
};
}

struct my_str_wrap {
  struct my_str w;
};

void helper(struct my_str& obj) {
  std::cout << obj.data;
}

void  my_class::method() {
  helper(field->w);
}
```